# OpenGL font rendering and texture packing : what if out of space?

Tags: opengl, fonts

To render text with OpenGL, one common solution is to pack the characters into one texture, for example 512x512, and renderer the string with one draw call. However, how to handle the case where the texture can't fit all the characters, if for example we use plenty of unicode characters? The string will need to use different textures. How to handle it?

Comment: Given OpenGL 4.6, the minimum size a array texture has to support are 2048 layers of 2048x2048 textures. For character sizes of 64x64 pixels, that's more than 2 million characters.

Comment: Then, it is your choice: make the texture bigger, or use more textures. The options seem quite obvious. What are you confused about?

Comment: One non-obvious option is to take a 4-channel texture and store completely different 1-channel data in each channel, so you effectively get 4 times the texture space, as long as you don't want to store colour.

Comment: @user253751 that is a nice idea. I do not really know I just started text rendering and it was a bit unclear for me. So OpenGL can bind very big textures without problem, I thought the limit where low like 4k maximum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the options for you are obvious:

1. Make the texture bigger
2. Make the font smaller (OpenGL can stretch it out when rendering, but it'll look bad)
3. Use more textures
4. Don't put all the characters in the texture, at least not all at the same time. (Change the texture when you need different characters)

and one non-obvious option:

5. Since you only need one colour channel for font rendering (because you select the colour when you render the text, and don't store it in the texture) you can get 4x as much data in a same-size texture by taking the 4 RGBA channels of one texture and storing a separate 1-channel texture in each. (The texture still takes up 4x as many bytes as a 1-channel texture, but not 4x as many pixels)

But those are your options.